# (Binomial) Distribution problem.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have two questions concerning the following: A pension (B&B) has three guest-rooms. The pension is opened from April - November (244 days, 35 weeks). Last year the distribution of the number of occupied rooms was as follows:
0 occupied rooms on 31 days, 1 occupied room on 22 days, 2 occupied rooms on 107 days and 3 occupied rooms on 84 days.

Now I'd have to calculate the probability that in a week (seven days) the pension is full for at least 5 days and state the assumptions you make.

I thought the following is correct, however I am not sure:
The probability that the pension is full on a day is: $84/244 = 0.34$
Let $Y =$ number of days the B&B is full in a week.
Then, $Y\sim Bin( n=7, p = 0.34)$
such that $P(Y > 4) = P(y=5) + P(y=6) + P(y=7) = \dots = 0.049$.

I am really not sure if this is correct?

Furthermore, suppose that the owner of the B&B has asked her daughter to come and visit her. This is only possible if there are no guests in the B&B. Calculate the exact 90% confidence interval for the number of days within she can visit her mother. (Use the exact probability distribution, so no Chebycheff)

$T$ = The Number of days within she can visit her mother.

Then $T \sim Geom(p)$ with $p = \text{no guests} / \text{total days} = 31/244 = 0.13$

So, I thought now you'd have to calculate the following interval: 
$P(c < T < d) = 0.90$.

I don't know how to go further without a known $c$ or $d$. So I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on how to format your math.

Comment: For the first part, you have to make the assumption that every day in the season the hotel has the equal probability being full. Then I would  use the fractions for calculation: $\sum_{k=5}^7 {7 \choose k} \left(\frac{21}{61}\right)^k\cdot \left(1-\frac{21}{61}\right)^{7-k}\approx 5.2\%$. Beside this the first part looks correct.